# parse exception convert json to object Zend-studio

Tags: github, zend-studio

When i'm trying to connect to my Git-hub  repository with Zend studio 10.0 shows this message:
" parse exception converting JSON to object "

Comment: I'm running 9.0.4 and it happens there too...

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to simply use the "File" -> "New Project from Git" option instead of the "New Project from GitHub" option. You can then just paste in the URL for the project (which is easy to copy from GitHub) and enter your GitHub user name and password and it will clone the repo in, I'm guessing, exactly the same way that the "New Project from GitHub" process would have done.